# Bitpay android integration

Tags: android, bitpay

Can any give me some direction how can I integrate Bitpay in my android app, I have searched for documentation, didn't find anything useful.I tried to run their sample app from GitHub https://github.com/bitpay/android-sdk-sample

but getting this error.

```
12-14 09:19:22.140 1665-1665/com.bitpay.sample.musicstore W/System.err: 
com.bitpay.sdk.controller.BitPayException: Error - failed to deserialize 
BitPay server response (Invoice) : Unrecognized field "buyerTotalBtcAmount" 
(class com.bitpay.sdk.model.Invoice), not marked as ignorable (31 known 
properties: "itemDesc", "notificationURL", "guid", "price", 
"transactionSpeed", "orderId", "paymentUrls", "refundAddresses", 
"buyerFields", "currency", "transactions", "physical", "fullNotifications" 
[truncated]])

12-14 09:19:22.141 1665-1665/com.bitpay.sample.musicstore W/System.err:     
at [Source: {"facade":"pos/invoice","data"
{"url":"https://test.bitpay.com/invoice?id=Lh6f8nJmmr3bUpmt7hUzpJ","status":"new","btcPrice":"0.157762","btcDue":"0.157765","price":2546.43,"currency":"USD","buyerTotalBtcAmount":"0.157765","invoiceTime":1513221560521,"expirationTime":1513222460521,"currentTime":1513221560540,"guid":"43408381","id":"Lh6f8nJmmr3bUpmt7hUzpJ","lowFeeDetected":false,"btcPaid":"0.000000","rate":16141,"exceptionStatus":false,"refundAddressRequestPending":false,"addresses":{"BTC":"n2Li7v6Eh43uAM41B8wEwbTG9X2NgohU6X"},"paymentSubtotals":{"BTC":15776200},"paymentTotals":{"BTC":15776500},"paymentUrls":{"BIP21":"bitcoin:n2Li7v6Eh43uAM41B8wEwbTG9X2NgohU6X?amount=0.157765","BIP72":"bitcoin:n2Li7v6Eh43uAM41B8wEwbTG9X2NgohU6X?amount=0.157765&r=https://test.bitpay.com/i/Lh6f8nJmmr3bUpmt7hUzpJ","BIP72b":"bitcoin:?r=https://test.bitpay.com/i/Lh6f8nJmmr3bUpmt7hUzpJ","BIP73":"https://test.bitpay.com/i/Lh6f8nJmmr3bUpmt7hUzpJ"},"bitcoinAddress":"n2Li7v6Eh43uAM41B8wEwbTG9X2NgohU6X","buyerPaidBtcMinerFee":"0.000003","supportedTransactionCurrencies":{"BTC":{"enabled":true}},"exRates":{"USD":16141},"exchangeRates":{"BTC":{"USD":16141}},"token":"3BjTnM1C47mHNgZZy2vS6KQciyhYZB3sstFCQ9SgLLoFGGfiCfCpY9Jf6V7ZEHTMtL"}}; line: 1, column: 212] (through reference chain: com.bitpay.sdk.controller.InvoiceWrapper["data"]->com.bitpay.sdk.model.Invoice["buyerTotalBtcAmount"])
12-14 09:19:22.141 1665-1665/com.bitpay.sample.musicstore W/System.err:     
at com.bitpay.sdk.controller.BitPay.createInvoice(BitPay.java:199)
12-14 09:19:22.141 1665-1665/com.bitpay.sample.musicstore W/System.err:     
at com.bitpay.sdk.android.BitPayAndroid$CreateInvoiceTask.doInBackground(BitPayAndroid.java:395)
12-14 09:19:22.141 1665-1665/com.bitpay.sample.musicstore W/System.err:     
at com.bitpay.sdk.android.BitPayAndroid$CreateInvoiceTask.doInBackground(BitPayAndroid.java:383)
12-14 09:19:22.141 1665-1665/com.bitpay.sample.musicstore W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
12-14 09:19:22.141 1665-1665/com.bitpay.sample.musicstore W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-14 09:19:22.142 1665-1665/com.bitpay.sample.musicstore W/System.err:     
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
12-14 09:19:22.142 1665-1665/com.bitpay.sample.musicstore W/System.err:     
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
12-14 09:19:22.142 1665-1665/com.bitpay.sample.musicstore W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by web service. Just create one web service where you have to integrate bitcoin properly using bitcoin library (https://github.com/bitpay/php-bitpay-client) and tutorial https://github.com/bitpay/php-bitpay-client/tree/master/examples/tutorial. Web service should be one PHP file and you have load to android web view control. And manage the success or failure messages.